# Sample size effects on R squared

Tags: regression, self-study

Let's say I generated 2*n values $X_{1},X_{2},...X_{n},Y_{1},Y_{2}...Y_{n}$ from a normal distribution N(10,15) and n = 10,100,1000,20000 and fitted the regression line. Here's some result
$$
n=10, R^{2} =0.03919\\
n=100,R^{2} = 0.004381\\
n=1000, R^{2} = 0.0001705\\
n=20000,R^{2} =  2.386e-06 
$$
from the result as n (sample size) start to increase, $R^{2}$ start to get smaller. how can i explain this phenomena (a hint will do)? thanks

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that you only ran these simulations once.  If you run them a few times the results will vary.  You might get a smaller coefficient for the first one.  But in general the reason for this pattern is because the true correlation for the underlying population is 0 and your simulations are following the [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

Comment: thanks for the hint appreaciate. yes i ran this only one time

Comment: How could $R^2$ be negative?

Comment: @steko I don't believe anybody is claiming $R^2$ can be negative.  Where John refers to "true correlation" he means $R$.

Comment: Ok, I just got confused reading that.